# Package module not found in Python 2.5, but found in 2.6

Tags: python, module, package

I have package structure that looks like this:

- ae

  - util

**util** contains a method **mkdir(dir)** that, given a path, creates a directory. If the directory exists, no error is thrown; the method fails silently.

The directory **ae** and its parent directory are both on my PYTHONPATH. When I try to use this method in *Python 2.6*, everything is fine. However, *Python 2.5* gives the following error:

```
util.mkdir(SOURCES)
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'mkdir'
```

Why is *Python 2.6* able to find this module and its method with no problems, but *Python 2.5* cannot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- do you `import ae.util` or `import util`? Either `ae` or its parent dir should be in PYTHONPATH, but not both
- verify you have the right `util` module by running `print util` (will print the module's source file)

Comment: I was sure to place ae's parent directory in my PYTHONPATH and not ae itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe Python 2.5 is accessing a different version of `util` that does not have the `mkdir` method.

Answer (score 0):

It depends where You call this method, and what Your import is. If You write:

```
from ae import util
util.mkdir(SOURCES)
```

everything should be ok.

The error occurs probably because of the difference in the import policy between Python 2.5 and 2.6.

Comment: What changed from 2.5 to 2.6 with respect to import?  I thought "absolute_import" (in `__future__`) was still required in 2.6, and was going to be the default only in 2.7 and 3.x.